# Having a "library" of jenkinsfiles

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have 1900 separate Java projects. At the moment, we thinking about introducing Jenkins. Many of the projects would need to have the same jenkinsfile, except for 1 or 2 parameters which need to be set.

In the Java projects, I would like to "import" jenkinsfiles, following the logic

```
Use jenkinsfile "Standard-Jar-Build" with parameters according to "project.properties"
```

What could be a way to have such a "jenkinsfile library"?

Comment: Have you read https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is probably what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the company I work for right now I created a set of jenkinsfiles that represent certain pipeline workflows. These workflows are generic and all the project specific configuration can be passed to the jenkinsfile using job parameters.
So the only thing projects have to do is "pipeline from SCM" and point to our script files and then customise is for their project using the available properties.
Also to keep the jenkinsfile small we also use the global library feature. We call it 'common' and it contains all kinds of methods that the jenkinsfiles can use.
Added bonus: everything in the common is automatically allowed, no whitelisting needed.